# How run Angular JS + Ionic application in WebStorm IDE?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, frontend, webstorm

I'm new in the domain of Front End development. But I need to make application (Client Side Angular + Ionic) running in WebStorm.

I didn't understood how run it and how see its look and feel in the Browser.

This is the architecture of my App:

[image: Image of my app]

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the down arrow on the top right corner. And click `Edit configurations...`
2. Click `+` in the top left corner of the newly popped window. Add a npm configuration.
3. Choose the `ionic:serve` script.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08YyI.png)

PS: Actually you can just run `ionic serve` in your terminal.

(I'm quite sorry I can't post images, so I use link instead, it may bother you to click the links to see these screenshots.)

Answer (score -1):

thank's for reply but I used generator Ionic for my App .

You can focus on this architecture is not the same of an ionic app.
So when I run " ionic serve" it can't perform.and said that the project is not ionic project.

I didn't found anything on the internet concerning how run a M-ionic generator app.